# Missions timeline not working after loading while takeoff

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am having an issue where i execute the `startTakeOff()` method, and the callback of this method is returned **before** (0.5 meters) the drone got to the height he suppose to (1.2 meters) - this part is documented (`startTakeoff()`) - which is a bit weird. After the callback is returned i am loading the actions to the timeline (getting a success callback), and then firing the `startTimeline()` method, i've also registered a listener that prints all timeline's event status, and what i see is that the timeline started, then the `GoToAction` (first in the timeline) is started **but** the drone doing nothing, doesn't move or do anything.

If i clean the timeline, reload the actions, and fire `startTimeline()` again (w/o calling to `stopTimeline()`) it works as it suppose to.

My question is - is there a 'clean' way to delay takeOff's callback? Or make the timeline run w/o reloading it? By 'clean' i mean that i can set a custom timeout that will load and start the timeline, but it is not the best practice...

Answer (score 0):

No the OSDK fires the callback as it leaves the ground, your only option is to observe and wait for it to reach 1.2m.

Answer (score 0):

OSDK only provide you with some sample. It is not 100% sure of working. You should think and get a solution to your problem.

In your case, the delay they put is without any guarantee. you need accurate feedback to make it sable

You can use a system such as SVO to achieve this. https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo

SVO gives you feedback of ur current drone status. So instead of using delay

```
start take off
while uav not at 1.2 meter -> (take off running) do nothing

while uav airbone -> do the thing you want
```

Additionally you can put timeout in, in case overloads and drone cant take off successfully.

[image]

I saw people getting SVO / PTAM / Vinsmono working on android phone before. So i think you could do the same.